# Leaflet not accepting boundaries

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

Before I ask my question I want to say that I'm fairly new to CSS and a complete newbie to LeafLet.

A few months ago I created a html file that showed part of a map on the left side and some text on the right side. The map provider was Google Maps.

The file looked like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
            #root, html, body {
                height: 98%;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            #map {
                float: left;
                width: 34.8%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: visible;
            }

            #content {
                float: right;
                width: 65%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div id="content">This is just a test This is just a test This is just a test</div>
        </div>

        <script>

            function initMap() {
                var nz = {lat: 51.5, lng: 0.0};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 8,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    center: nz
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since Google changed it's license policy and shows a "For development purposes only" on my map I thought about changing the map provider and switch to OpenStreetMap and LeafLet.

So I took my old file and only changed the code showing the map. Now the file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA==" crossorigin=""></script>
        <style>
            #root, html, body {
                height: 98%;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            #map {
                float: left;
                width: 34.8%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: visible;
            }

            #content {
                float: right;
                width: 65%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div id="content">This is just a test This is just a test This is just a test</div>
        </div>

        <script>
            //create map
            var centerLat = 51.5;
            var centerLon = 0.0;
            var initialZoom = 8;

            var map = L.map('map', {
                center: [centerLat, centerLon],
                zoom: initialZoom
            });
            var content = document.getElementById('content');

            //set map tiles source
            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
                maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(map);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this LeafLet map doesn't stay inside the boundaries of the div-element it should be shown in.
If I remove the part with the `tileLayer`, then it stays inside the div but doesn't show a map.
Googling for that problem only found some people saying there's a CSS file missing, but I included the LeafLet CSS file like the LeafLet documentation says (copy & paste, so no typo possible).
The map is not only shown outside it's boundaries, if I want to change the part of the map that is shown with the mouse (click and drag) then the complete div moves (or is it an extra layer?).

What can I do to show the map inside it's boundaries and keep the map inside it's boundaries even when clicking and dragging?

Since I don't know exactly where the error comes from I added a few tags that might not have anything to do with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS for the #map looks like.

```
        #map {
            float: left;
            width: 34.8%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: visible;
        }
```

Remove the line that says overflow:visible. Then it looks pretty good.

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRzrdX

Comment: You are right, thank you. But why is it working when I remove the `tileLayer` part of the code and why is it working in the google version of the file?

Comment: Before you run the tilelayer part of the code in javascript you have a map object loaded into your html DOM. At the time it is loaded in, it just shows an empty map container (gray color). Then when you ask tillayer to populate the map object with tiles, it fills it up with many small png images. These images are sticking out of the container. If you have overflow set to hidden, you don't see them, but if overflow is visible you do. 
Google maps code had overflow attribute in CSS set to auto:
Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow